# How do I disable ros2 launch log handlers?

Tags: ros2, launch

When I execute my `ros2 run` command, I get a console log like
`2023-12-06 11:47:16.119 | INFO     | robot_fastapi_service:main:354 - Starting Robot FastAPI Service.`

However, when I run my `ros2 launch` command, I get a log line like `[robot_fastapi_service-13] 2023-12-06 11:55:25.702 | INFO     | robot_fastapi_service:main:354 - Starting Robot FastAPI Service.`

How do I configure `ros2 launch` to not add on the process prefix?